# how to specify the style contains : in react tax

Tags: html, css

I am write a css to show the UI element active or not, this is the css:

```
.original-bg {
    background-image: url('../../../asset/image/tool/grid.png');
    min-width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 24px;
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.original-bg:active {
    border-color: blue
}
```

I want the border turn to blue when the element selected. in the tsx file, I write it like this:

```
<a title="origin" className={imgBg === "origin"?"original-bg:active":"original-bg"}></a>
<a title="red" className="bg-red"></a>
```

when state imgBg was origin, turn the origin image border to blue. Now when I added this condition code, the origin image just disappear, am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, try defining a separate class name for the active state, like .original-bg-active, and adding or removing that class name dynamically based on the value of imgBg. I'll put some code for you to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make these changes to your code and see if it solves the problem, if not I will try another approach

```
.original-bg {
    background-image: url('../../../asset/image/tool/grid.png');
    min-width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 24px;
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.original-bg-active {
    border-color: blue;
}


<a title="origin" className={`original-bg ${imgBg === "origin" ? "original-bg-active" : ""}`}></a>
<a title="red" className="bg-red"></a>
```

Comment: I tried your code, problem solved. thank you for your time and patients.